# How to get value from span, but no child elements inside of it

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get only one value from my spans. This is how my code looks like:

HTML:

```
<span id="box1">
    value1
        <span class="box2">value2</span>
        <span class="box3">value3</span>
</span>
```

jQuery:

```
var str = $('#box1').text();
alert(str);
```

This returns:

```
value1
    value2
    value3
```

How can I get "value1"?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate because that one had a requirement to NOT change the HTML. Dunno if that matters here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var text = $('#box1').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Comment: Thank you. Pretty weird line, but my code is as weird as that too.

Comment: @user2035638 if the answer helps don't forget to check the green tick to mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 2 minutes" I do keep hitting it every minute, wont let me mark it yet! :D

Answer (score 0):

Put its own `<span>` around it.

```
<span id="box1">
    <span id="span1">value1</span>
        <span class="box2">value2</span>
        <span class="box3">value3</span>
</span>
```

Then do this

```
var str = $('#span1').text();
```

Comment: Yeah, but I really cannot change my code, so this wont work. Thank you for your help tho!